# What is the differences between INT and FTH?

Tags: dark-souls-series

I finished dark souls 2 in STR build and I know about how DEX and STR works and what is differences for example:

STR weapons are powerful and deal a lot of damage to enemIES and weapons are big but slow and character is more like a tank. More using shield instead of roll (optional)

DEX weapons are fast but deal less damage and the weapons are small. Character is Fast and roll more than using shield (optional)

So here is differences between DEX and STR. Can some one explain differences between FTH and INT like that? And more complete like explaining about weapons difference, scrolls difference, character and class difference,etc.

And if you can please tell differences of INT and FTH in dark souls?

Comment: I suggest asking difference between DS1 and DS2 stats as separate question

Answer (score 5):

See [Stats](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/stats):

> **Intelligence**: Meets Intelligence requirements for equipment and sorceries;
>   Increases damage on weapons with INT scaling;
>   Magic Adjustment UP for most catalysts
>
> **Faith**: Meets Faith requirements for equipment and miracles;
>   Increases damage on weapons with FTH scaling;
>   Magic Adjustment UP for most talismans;
>   Magic Defense UP

So, basically, if you are caster and prefer Miracles - lvl FTH and use weapon with better FTH scaling, if you prefer sorceries - lvl INT and use weapon with INT scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your assumptions about STR and DEX may be a bit shallow and general. Some weapons benefit from both stats, albeit usually with better scaling to one or the other.

Your question focuses on the INT and FTH stats though. The answer arghtype gave does answer it in a very literal way. As far as play-style, INT has more offensive sorceries early in the game, while FTH gives the player the ability to cast various defensive, healing, or stat-increasing buffs earlier on.

The above gets subverted a little with Hexes. These dark sorceries and miracles rely on both stats, and some enemies are impacted more or less than compared to a similar "regular" sorcery or miracle. Hexes were introduced in the DLC for Dark Souls, and were expanded upon in the main game of Dark Souls 2. Again, keep in mind that these are **generalizations** and not always true.

Furthermore, one could take into account that all four stats together can potentially scale and be a requirement for some weapons. For example, the Black Knight Greatsword (one of my personal favorites) has certain stat requirements for all four of those stats, and scales on both STR and DEX.

Sources: [Fextralife Dark Souls wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/), my own experience.